# How to show error message under apex:inputtextarea

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, customlabel, bootstrap

On my page visualforce page I have a few fields that on submit validation will run. For some reason the error is not displaying under the  textarea but its working for other fields on my page. How can I solve this? The errorMsg class is not being applied to the textarea

On my visualforce page I have this

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
   <apex:outputLabel value="
   {!$ObjectType.Employment_History__c.fields.Job_description__c.label}" 
   styleClass="control-label"/>  
   <apex:inputTextarea value="{!emp.Job_description__c}" styleClass="form-
   control" />
</div>
```

In my controller I am just checking if the field is blank if so display the error message that's stored in a custom label.

```
if (String.isBlank(emp.Job_description__c)){
   emp.Job_description__c.addError(System.Label.Validation
   EmploymentDescription);
   doNotsubmit = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using apex:inputField instead. This enforces FLS, and also automatically provides an error mechanism for when you use addError.

Comment: How can I display the message if the value for the  inputfield  has been changed in the apex controller to public list<string> empCloneListEndDate {get; set;}.  To be clear how can I check if this field is blank if its now set to  List <string> and display the error message under the field?

Comment: @user51208 You can't use addError. You'd have to arrange for your own output mechanism. I don't know of a way to do so otherwise.